# Is there a way to call all children of a base classes functions in C++?

Tags: c++, performance

I have a lot of scenes in my application which all contain the same functions such as Update() Render() Initialise(). The way i am doing it just now is to declare all scenes and call all functions individually. Is there a way to make these scenes derive from a base class where I can call  Update() on the base class which will in turn call all update functions that are derived from this class?

Cheers.

Comment: You should give code example for what you exactly want. Also see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You'd better ask this question on code review with a sample of your code. Not on stack overflow.

Comment: I was hesitating to close vote this question between "unclear what you're asking" and "too broad"

Comment: you can make a Scene graph and  at update method call update function for each child. As far as I know this approach is very popular and used in cocos2dx engine.Note: it's not answer on your original question cuz you don't  make clear relationships between scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Club the child objects by pushing to a container, so that the derived member functions can be collectively called like so:

```
class base {
public: virtual void Update() = 0;
};

class A: public base {
public:  void Update() {}
};

class B : public base {
public:  void Update() {}
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<base>> group;
    group.push_back(make_unique<base>(A()));
    group.push_back(make_unique<base>(B()));

    for (auto& e : group) {
        e.get()->Update(); // update all the objects
    }

}
```

Comment: Please write a few words about the code. Code without explanations is less useful.